# How should I create a stylized, semi-waxy skin in Blender (Eevee)?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine, zbrush

I am attempting to recreate the skin material created by [Dmytro Bajda](https://www.artstation.com/demonu4) within zbrush, but in blender instead. I am specifically attempting to create procedural skin that looks like this:
[image]
^This is from their post "[More sketches and WIPs](https://www.artstation.com/artwork/zAJn62)".
For reference, within zbrush, this material is based upon the default "skin4" matcap. It has a unique specularity curve and about half of the wax modifier within in.
*This also has been polypainted (in areas like the lips, eyes)*

I have tried numerous times, with the principle BDSF and without, but cannot seem to get the finish/color correct.

**More color-accurate attempt:**
[image]
[image]

**And a more texture-accurate attempt:**
[image]
[image]

At this point, I feel I am needlessly complicating the material; thus, I am curious if anyone might be able to give some insights into how to create a material like this one.

Thank you for reading all of this! I hope you have a wonderful day-!

Comment: One question first - what is your lighting setup?

Comment: @AllenSimpson I have three point lights each with a radius of 1.5. They two side ones have a brightness of 100, and the center one has a brightness of 180. Photos Here: https://imgur.com/a/JozvREn